# TextAd can still be retrieved even if it was deleted

Tags: google-ads-api

I Observed that when i deleted my TextAd and try to get it via API it still can be retrieved, is this a bug by Adwords? or there is a valid explanation on why this is happening?
i expect that if the TextAd is deleted it will can't be longer be retrieve using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also see a deleted AdWords ad on in the UI if you select "All ads" in the filter dropdown. AdWords ads cannot be fully removed from the account. The API allows for a programmatic way to access what you have in the UI.